# Conda Skeleton Installing Same Package For Different Python Versions

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to install sklearn-pandas for data science on my conda environments so I switch to my Python2 Conda environment and use skeleton to build it in:

```
conda skeleton pypi sklearn-pandas
conda-build sklearn-pandas
conda install --use-local sklearn-pandas
```

The problem is, this builds in a bunch of python 3 dependencies, and at the end of it all when I run python --version I get

```
Python 3.6.6
```

This means that it had to upgrade the python version of the environment to accommodate the package it installed.

I think this library should be compatible with Python 2, it even says in its Git repo "build universal wheel compatible with python 2 and python 3".

What arguments do I need to pass to conda skeleton, build, and install so that it installs and builds it for Python 2 and doesn't do this unwanted upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - you only need to add one flag to the conda-build step. It's:

```
conda-build --python 2.7 sklearn-pandas
```

Although in the conda skeleton stage of the installation it appears to bring in py36 packages, once you do this conda-build step with the flag it replaces them with py27.

Comment: Conda skeleton goes to find the package from PyPI and build a recipe. The recipe says where to get the source code and the dependencies, so it doesn't care what version of Python its for. However, the build step defaults to using the same version of Python as in your base environment. Hence, if you want to build for a different version of Python you need to specify.